# upload csv file to appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv

I need to upload some CSV files to my appengine backend project.
I think the commands described here does not work in the last version of appcfg.

[How to build a mobile app with an App Engine backend](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/)

This is the command but it does not works for me.

[image]

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the appcfg.cmd no the appcfg.py. I don't see upload_data for cmd but it does come up if you run 'appcfg.py upload_data --help'. The doc you linked also uses the .py version.